# cannot mention minimum value to the numeric component

Tags: syncfusion

Cannot mention minimum value and need to customize the arrow button

```
<NumericTextBoxComponent

                        validateDecimalOnType={true}
                        format='n2'
                        placeholder="Applied"
                        enabled={this.props.overApplied}
                        change={this.props.handleOverApplied}
                        value={this.props.added.value}
                    />
```

Comment: Thanks for your information but if I set min={0} then why it accepts "-"(minus). How to mask or disable this.

Answer (score 1):

**Query-1: Setting minimum value**

If you want to set minimum/maximum values in NumericTextBox, Please refer to the below range validation online sample,

```
<!-- Initialize Numeric Textbox -->
<ejs-numerictextbox id="numeric" min="10" max="100" value="15"></ejs-numerictextbox>
```

Sample : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/NumericTextBox/RangeValidation#/material

**Query-2: Customizing arrow buttons**

To customize the arrow buttons to different icons, you can refer to the below how-to documentation page,
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/numerictextbox/how-to/customize-the-spin-buttons-up-and-down-arrow/

**Note:**
We assumed that you are using ASP.Net Core and Provided the above information. If you are using different platform, the same links are available in that platform itself.